# Sustituir keywords de un fichero separado por comas en un texto con variables

Tags: php, foreach

Llevo días pensando este script ya tengo código hecho, pero no logro darle forma a lo que realmente necesito.

1. Tengo 5 keywords en un txt, separadas por | , las leo y quiero almacenarlas en un array (para controlar su posición) o guardar cada una en una VARIABLE.

FICHERO: Apple|Sony|Samsung|Xiaomi|LG

1.1 El script debe reemplazar una a una las keywords para usar keyTITLE como principal para cada interacción.

2. Tengo un texto (lo ideal sería sacarlo desde un fichero de texto, pero lo tengo en una Variable), ese texto contiene 5 variables.

EJM texto

> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para $variabletitulo
>
> Especializados en $variable1 y $variable2 , contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.
>
> Más información de soporte en $variable3 , $variable4.

3. Los TITULOS deben seguir el orden del fichero es decir primero el titulo APPLE, segundo SONY,  SAMSUNG,  XIAOMI y LG.
4. y el resto de palabras restantes del array, que se coloquen en cualquier posición de las elegidas aleatoriamente, y el resultado debería ser ASI:

> El texto daria 5 textos asi:
>
> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para APPLE   Especializados en SONY y
>   SAMSUNG, contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.   Más información
>   de soporte en $XIAOMI, LG.
>
> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para SONY  Especializados en XIAOMI
>   y LG, contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.  Más información de
>   soporte en APPLE, SAMSUNG.
>
> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para SAMSUNG   Especializados en LG y
>   XIAOMI, contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.    Más información de
>   soporte en LG, APPLE.
>
> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para XIAOMI    Especializados en APPLE
>   y SAMSUNG, contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.     Más información
>   de soporte en SONY, LG.
>
> Ofrecemos servicio de reparacion para LG    Especializados en APPLE y
>   SONY, contacta nuestros servicios en 9191919191.  Más información de
>   soporte en SAMSUNG, APPLE.

En el código que si puedo lo comparto por link de paste bin, esta todo hecho sólo faltan los 2 puntos mencionados. 
Espero alguien pueda colaborarme con ello, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que entendí de tu pregunta, ya tienes cargado el fichero, y asumo que se encuentra en una variable, digamos `$linea`, para convertir esa línea en un arreglo, debes usar `explode()`:

```
$arr = explode(',', $linea);
```

Y listo, ya puedes iterar como quieras usando un `foreach`. Y si lo que quieres es un reemplazo en el string de venta, y estás seguro que siempre tiene seis "espacios", es tan sencillo como:

```
echo "<p>Reparación de $arr[0]</p>";
echo "<p>Solución de averías en móviles $arr[0] o $arr[1], visitanos ... como $arr[2]";
```

Comment: Buenas Luisfer gracias por tu respuesta!, si es correcto lo que comentas, tengo el código no se si se pueda copiar aqui el link para verlo, el código mio lo que hace es Reemplazar las Variables en el texto, pero repetidamente.

Busco lograr esto:
1) Este es el resultado que quiero Conseguir,  Los TITULOS deben seguir el orden del fichero es decir primero el titulo APPLE, segundo SONY,  SAMSUNG,  XIAOMI y LG. (estan en amarillo en la captura)
2) El resto de palabras restantes del array, que se coloquen en cualquier posición aleatoriamente, y el resultado debería ser como esa imagen.